# Unable to retrieve the model property value in Java script in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to access model property on the view side  but it not working as expected.
Here is my code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
    var message = Model.errorMessage;

}
```

Up to the above code on my view the value which is passed from the controller side is received in the var message.
The problem is here:

```
if ('@message' == "AlreadyTaken") {
                    $("#alertSection").show();
                }
```

It is executed as

```
 if ('' == "AlreadyTaken") {
                $("#alertSection").show();
            }
```

I have tried so many solutions but all in vain

Comment: Just a question, are you putting your Javascript inline in same cshtml file or in a separate JS file?

Comment: Same cshtml file @Markuzy

Comment: Able to post the model class here? And when you put a breakpoint in your controller action right before returning to view, what do you see when you mouse over your model? Is the errorMessage present?

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the value into something that JS can access e.g.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
    var message = Model.errorMessage;

}

<input id="myMessage" type="text" value="@message" hidden />
```

then in JS

```
if($('#myMessage').val() == 'AlreadyTaken'){
    $("#alertSection").show();
}
```

assuming you are firing the JS on document ready.

Comment: The input tag doesn't get anything in the value property

Comment: I think the value gets changed somewhere there in the middle.. tried hard but failed

Answer (score 0):

if your full cshtml code is like the one below

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var message = Model.errorMessage;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('@message' == "AlreadyTaken") {
        $("#alertSection").show();
    }
</script>
```

The only reasons the javascript part would be rendered as

```
 if ('' == "AlreadyTaken") {
            $("#alertSection").show();
        }
```

are:

- Model.errorMessage is null
- Model.errorMessage is an empty string
- Model.errorMessage is an instance of an object whose ToString() method call results in a null or empty string

If this is not the case maybe there is some code in between that changes the value of `message`

Answer (score -1):

Your code below executes in the server side.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage";
    var message = Model.errorMessage;

}
```

However,the code below is the javascript code that executes in the client side.

```
if ('@message' == "AlreadyTaken") {
                    $("#alertSection").show();
                }
```

The client side has no idea what @message is. In order to make this work, you will need to expose message variable as a javascript string.

```js
<script>
 let javascriptMessage = '@Html.Raw(message)'
 if(javascriptMessage == 'AlreadyTaken') {
     $("#alertSection").show();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to get at,  but razor syntax with the "@" will always execute server side, even when placed in inline JavaScript on the same page. However, this begs the question for the thread starter: Is the javascript in the razor view or in another file? (I am not the one who downvoted you btw)

Comment: The javascript is in the razor file. Yes, the syntax with "@" will execute in the server side. That's why we create a variable javascriptMessage  when building the razor page. This will be loaded in the client side with the value copied from "@message" when the page is loaded.

Comment: I have already tried it but same story @Kshitiz Shakya

Comment: @Ummar, have you declared javascriptMessage as global variable? If so what is the value of it  ? You can use the debugger to see the value of javascriptMessage.